# Генерация псевдослучайных чисел

Tags: c

В программе для заполнения массива нужно генерировать случайные числа, при этом разные для каждого заполнения массива. `srand(time(NULL))` не работает должным образом, обновляя рандомные значения один раз за всю программу, а нужно после каждого вызова функции заполнения.

```
void FillArr(int type)
{
    int c;
    switch (type) {
    case 0:
        ...
    case 1:
        srand(time(0));
        for (int i = 0; i < P; i++) {
            for (int j = 0; j < M; j++) {
                for (int k = 0; k < N; k++) Arr3D[i][j][k] = rand();
            }
        }
        break;
    case 2:
        ...
    } 
}
```

Часть кода из `main()`

```
main(){
    for (int i = 0; i < measurements_number; i++)
    {
        if (r == 1) srand(time(NULL));
        FillArr(r);
        Res[i] = Shell_1();
    }
```

Comment: Зачем? Чего вы хотите добиться? Чтобы при каждом вызове функции заполнения получались одни и те же данные?

Comment: @Harry как раз наоборот, я же написал, что при каждом вызове должны записываться разные числа. Сейчас работает так: при каждом запуске программы рандомные числа обновляются, а при вызове функции нет. в итоге у меня каждый раз массив заполняется одной и той же комбинацией рандомных чисел, а меняется эта комбинация только при перезапуске программы

Comment: Какая-то ерунда. В вашем `case 1` сделано именно так, чтоб заполнение массива шло каждый раз одинаково. Если надо всегда и все разное - `srand(time(0))` только один раз, сразу в начале `main()`, **и больше ни разу нигде**.

Comment: @Harry спасибо, заработало, будем знать)))